# Почему не изменяется значение глобальной переменной после присвоения?

Tags: python, global-variables

Прошу помощи в вопросе изменения глобальной переменной из функции. При присвоении ей в функции некого значения, глобальная переменная не изменяется. В простых примерах с global все работает на ура, а в моем коде почему-то нет. Если несложно, то может быть кто-то популярно объяснит мне причину?
P.S. Я не студент(к сожалению уже очень давно) и не хочу прохалявить и сдать зачет. Изучаю python самостоятельно, а данный скрипт - это парсинг ответа моего датчика освещенности для отображения в GUI. Заранее благодарен.

Мой код:

```
import requests

ESP_Light_Sensor: int=0

def parsing_ESP():
  global ESP_Light_Sensor
  try:
    url= "http://192.168.0.110/sensors/adci1/"
    r= requests.get(url)
    r.encoding = "UTF8"
    print(r.text)
    with open('test.html', 'w') as output_file:
      output_file.write(r.text)
    with open('test1.txt', 'w') as output_file:
      output_file.write(r.text)

    f = open('test1.txt')
    str1=f.read()
    f.close()

    str2=str1[str1.find(";") + 1 : ]
    str3=str2[str2.find(":") + 1 : str2.find(";")]
    ESP_Light_Sensor = int(str3)

  except:
    str3=-1
    pass
  return str3
```

Comment: а вы проверяли, меняется ли ваша глобальная переменная в блоке `try`. И самое главное, зачем вы работаете с методом global? передавайте свою переменную в функцию, и возвращайте ее из функции. Так канонически правильнее и надежнее.

Comment: Да, глобальная переменная в блоке try изменяется. Проверял. Я понимаю правильность передачи переменных в функцию и возврата из нее, но дело в том, что мне нужно некоторое время хранить данные в переменной и обращаться к ней(переменной) не вызывая снова эту функцию для получения последнего значения. Это обусловлено чисто хардверными условиями. И вообще интересно узнать в чем причина такого поведения скрипта. Спасибо!

Comment: Всем спасибо, вопрос снят! Нужно было использовать += вместо =.